# Three20 image from file folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, three20

I am saving a UIImage using following codeThis image is saved in My application's Documents folder.

```
NSString *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(currentImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

How to get back this image in Three20 TTThumbsViewController? Somebody please help me. I am confused with the path of this UIImage.

I tried file:///Users/sijo/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/4.0.1/Applications/869B4AE9-A3DD-4F42-868E-E8863B15FAC3/Documents/Test.png

But this image am getting in safari browser. But in my iphone app, its shows following error

> [NSURLResponse allHeaderFields]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7062d30
>   2010-08-27 20:29:04.304 Tides and Weather[56179:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURLResponse allHeaderFields]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7062d30'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering to my own question .

http://scope.three20.info/where-does-documents-correspond-to-in-my-project-t34.html

> @"documents://Test.png"

did the trick..